# how to close mat menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11, angular-material-11

[image]

Hello, I have several matMenu  for example #status="matMenu",  #something = "matMenu",  i want to close active matMenu  on  child component's Approve button click.  child component  is in matMenu.   but every time  when I use
`

```
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, { static: false }) matMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  this.matMenuTrigger.closeMenu();`
```

it closes  only first matMenu. can anyone help me?

Comment: In that case I'd recommend using Angular's `@ViewChildren` instead which returns a list of the specified elements (see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). You can then iterate over them and check each element's `menuOpen` property and close it accordingly (see https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api).